# Is there a way to replace multiple keywords in a string and wrapping them with their own keyword?

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I have a string:

```
typed = "need replace this ap"
str = "hello I need to replace this asap"
```

so the end result I want would be this:

```
newStr = "hello I <bold>need</bold> to <bold>replace</bold> <bold>this</bold> as<bold>ap</bold>"
```

please don't mind the weird syntax.

I wonder if the order would matter, for example:

```
typed = "applicable app"
str = "the app is very applicable in many applications"
```

The end result I wish should be:

```
newStr = "the <bold>app</bold> is very <bold>applicable</bold> in many <bold>app</bold>lications"
```

right? is this possible?

Comment: check `String.replaceAllMapped` 
 / `String.splitMapJoin` methods official documentation

Comment: @fenchai did my solution help in anyway ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hey,If You can ignore the weird HTML syntax here,*

Then I have wrote a solution for you,

*Paste this code in **dart pad*** [here](https://dartpad.dev/)

```
removeDuplicates(var typed, var str) {
  Map<String, String> m = new Map<String, String>();

  var n = typed.length;
  String ans = "";

  //for storing the "typed" string  (word by word) into a map "m" variable for later searching purpose
  String temp = "";
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (typed[i] == " ") {
      m[temp] = temp;
      temp = "";
    } else {
      temp = temp + typed[i];
    }
  }
  
  //for storing the last word of the string "typed", coz loop will never find a space in last of the string
  m[temp] = temp;

  // map variable loop for search from map "m" in the "str" string, and matching if the word is present or not
  var n2 = str.length;
  String temp2 = "";
  for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
    if (str[j] == " ") {
      if (m.containsKey(temp2)) {
      } else {
        ans = ans + " " + temp2; //storing the "temp2" string into "ans" string, everytime it finds a space and if the string is not already present in the map "m"
      }
      temp2 = "";
    } else {
      temp2 = temp2 + str[j];
    }
  }

  //for searching for the last word of the string "str" in map "m", coz loop will never find a space in last of the string,
  if (m.containsKey(temp2)) {
  } else {
    ans = ans + " " + temp2;
  }

  return ans;
}

void main() {
  String typed = "need replace this ap";
  var str = "hello I need to replace this asap";
  String answer = removeDuplicates(typed, str);
  print(answer);
}
```

**Here**, I have made a `method` `removeDuplicates()` to simplify your work, You just have to pass those `string` in your `method`, and then it will `return` you the desired answer `string` by removing the `duplicates`, with a new `string`.

> **UPDATED CODE (TO SHOW HTML CODE):**

```
removeDuplicates(var typed, var str) {
  Map<String, String> m = new Map<String, String>();

  var n = typed.length;
  String ans = "";

  //for storing the "typed" string  (word by word) into a map "m" variable for later searching purpose
  String temp = "";
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (typed[i] == " ") {
      m[temp] = temp;
      temp = "";
    } else {
      temp = temp + typed[i];
    }
  }

  //for storing the last word of the string "typed", coz loop will never find a space in last of the string
  m[temp] = temp;

  print(m);

  // map variable loop for search from map "m" in the "str" string, and matching if the word is present or not
  var n2 = str.length;
  String temp2 = "";
  for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
    if (str[j] == " ") {
      if (m.containsKey(temp2)) {
        temp2 = "<bold>" + temp2 + "</bold> ";
        ans = ans + " " + temp2;
      } else {
        ans = ans +
            " " +
            temp2; //storing the "temp2" string into "ans" string, everytime it finds a space and if the string is not already present in the map "m"
      }
      temp2 = "";
    } else {
      temp2 = temp2 + str[j];
    }
  }

  //for searching for the last word of the string "str" in map "m", coz loop will never find a space in last of the string,
  if (m.containsKey(temp2)) {
    temp2 = "<bold>" + temp2 + "</bold> ";
    temp2 = "";
  } else {
    ans = ans + " " + temp2;
    temp2 = "";
  }

  return ans;
}

void main() {
  var typed = "applicable app";
  var str = "the app is very applicable in many applications";
  String answer = removeDuplicates(typed, str);
  print(answer);
}
```

**UPDATE 2** (*ALL THANKS TO PSKINK FOR THE `str.replaceAllMapped` APPROACH*)

```
replaceWithBoldIfExists(String typed, String str) {
  var n = typed.length;
  List<String> searchList = new List<String>();

  String temp = "";
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (typed[i] == " ") {
      searchList.add(temp);
      temp = "";
    } else {
      temp = temp + typed[i];
    }
  }

  searchList.add(temp);

  String pat = searchList.join('|');
  final pattern = RegExp(pat);

  final replaced =
      str.replaceAllMapped(pattern, (m) => '<bold>${m.group(0)}</bold>');
  return replaced;
}

void main() {
  var typed = "need replace this ap";
  var str = "hello I need to replace this asap";
  print(replaceWithBoldIfExists(typed, str));
}
```

Comment: the output is `the <bold>app</bold>  is very <bold>applicable</bold>  in many applications` - OP wants `the <bold>app</bold> is very <bold>applicable</bold> in many <bold>app</bold>lications`

Comment: I know, but It may give him/her overview or idea for the approach.

Comment: the idea is to use `String.replaceAllMapped` - as simple as this: `final pattern = RegExp("applicable|app");
final str = "the app is very applicable in many applications";
final replaced = str.replaceAllMapped(pattern, (m) => '<bold>${m.group(0)}</bold>');
print(str);
print('');
print(replaced);` - you can also use `String.splitMapJoin` method

Comment: what if he dont have any static string to convert, And he is having a set of string to convert and replace, then How would he write replace for every string, Please come up with a approach which suits any string and not a static string.

Comment: Thankyou Very Much @pskink for the idea and the str.replaceAllMapped solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229672/discussion-between-mukul-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

For future reference,
now you can use. `replaceAllMapped` method.

below is a simple usage for this purpose:

```
 String pattern = "string with multiple words";
  String stringToReplace = "we will change this string with multiple words with adding tags";
  String result = stringToReplace.replaceAllMapped(pattern,(match)=>"<anyTag>${match[0]}</anyTag>");
  print(result);
```

print result is :

```
we will change this <anyTag>string with multiple words</anyTag> with adding tags
```